# Seguing data from one UITableViewController to another UITableViewController via performSelector:withObject:

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

So what I am trying to do is I have an NSMutableArray of data I need to pass to another UITableViewController.  This NSMutableArray is an array of NSDictionaries that contain the information I want to be displayed in the title of each table view cell. Here is my code before I segue.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Title Query"]) {

        UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString* cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
        NSMutableArray* photosToBeShown = [self titleQuery:cellText];

          if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPhotoTitles:)]) {
              [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setPhotoTitles:) withObject: photosToBeShown];
              NSLog(@"%@", photosToBeShown);
          }      
    }

}
```

The method setPhotoTitles: that is called by the performSelector: withObject: is the setter of the property (NSMutableArray* ) photoTitles on the UITableViewController that I am seguing to because I wanted to collect the array so I could then call the methods below to set the titles of my table view cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photo Title Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
- (NSString *) titleForRow: (NSUInteger) row
{
    return self.photoTitles[row];
}
```

What happens when I run this code is I end up in an infinite loop with calls to my setter method (setPhotoTitles:).  Now my question is what is the right conceptual way to get around this problem or how can I implement it this way without ending up in an infinite loop.  I have all the information I need in my array but I need to pass the array to the new controller but also be able to use the UITableViewCell method to set the rows titles.

Comment: Did you override the setter for photoTitles?

Comment: Yes I did.  I now realize that was causing my problem but why can't you override the setter?

Comment: You should be able to -- what did you put in that method?

Comment: I deleted it when I fixed my problem and it was just lazy instantiation I thought that made sense but the function just kept getting called over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `prepareForSegue:` method, rather than overriding `setPhotoTitles:`, you should create a `NSArray` property in the destination view controller, as pass the photoTitles array to the `NSArray` property of the destination view controller. So your `prepareForSegue` method would look like this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Title Query"]) {

        UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString* cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
        NSMutableArray* photosToBeShown = [self titleQuery:cellText];

        YourCustomViewController *customViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        customViewController.photosArrayProperty = photosToBeShown;
    }

}
```

Comment: That works however every time prepareForSegue: sender: is called it adds another array to the property instead of erasing the array at the current property and initializing a new one.  So my property just continues to grow in length.

Comment: Nevermind this is an error of mine since I am using a mutable array my array continues to grow when I really need a new instance of an array instantiated.  Thanks for your help